# Восстановление пропущенных значений в данных

Tags: python, r, big-data

Подскажите библиотеку(аналог пакета "MICE" в R) для Python в которой реализованы методы восстановления пропусков в данных.

Comment: [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning)?

Comment: В sklearn реализации этих методов для восстановления пропусков нет. Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "восстановлением пропусков" - предсказание, интерполяцию, нечто другое?

Comment: Я имею ввиду предсказание.Сейчас я заменяю пропущенные значения в данных на 0 (что есть самым простым способом) и хочу улучшить результаты заменой пропусков более сложным методом. Я нашел описание двух способов это сделать : регрессионные модели и ЕМ-алгоритм. Но при этом не нашел их реализации на Python.

Answer (score 2):

Я не уверен на счет EM-алгоритма, но регрессионные методы представлены в [sklearn довольно неплохо](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/):

[SGD Regressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#regression)

[Lasso](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#lasso)

[ElasticNet](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#elastic-net)

[SVR kernel='rbf'](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#regression)

[Ensemble Regressors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html)

[Ridge Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ridge-regression)

[SVR kernel='linear'](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#regression)

Comment: Это не то что мне надо. Мне нужна функция которой на вход подается фрейм с пропущенными данными, а на выход мы получаем этот же фрейм но уже с заполненными пропусками

Comment: "пропуски" могут быть во многих (всех) колонках?

Comment: Да, пропуски могут быть во многих колонках

Comment: Посмотрите на [Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html), правда это скорее заполнение средними или медианными значениями, а не предсказывание

Comment: на Imputer я уже смотрел. там есть самые простые функиции но это не то что я ищу

Comment: а какие типы колонок?

Comment: В колонках расположины дейсвительные числа

Comment: Тогда можно интерполировать NaNs для каждой колонки